# Google SignIn integration in ionic app for iOS using capacitor

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, google-signin, capacitor

We are trying to implement GoogleSignIn in an ionic iOS app which uses capacitor. 
When tapping on the google button, an exception occurs

```
** Assertion failure in +[OIDScopeUtilities scopesWithArray:],
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Found illegal empty scope string.'
```

The capacitor.config.json contains the GoogleAuth Plugin as below and the scopes are also added.

```
"plugins": {
    "SplashScreen": {
      "launchShowDuration": 0
    },
    "GoogleAuth": {
        "scopes": [
        "profile",
        "email"
        ],
        "webClientId": "web client Id"
    }
  }
```

Removing the 'scopes' property or even the GoogleAuth Plugin inclusion from the capacitor.config.json file does not change the result observed.

I'm a relative newbie in this domain, Any suggestions to what could be going wrong, missing config?.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you check if the package name in Firebase is the same as your application? I had this problem a few times ago and found that I was checking the firebase.
2. Check that "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" is configured correctly in XCode, if you cannot see the reversed_client_id box, just add it manually.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IXyv.png)